# Dygraphs plot creates XML Parsing Error

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

When creating a custom plot I came across that Firefox's "Web Console" flagged an error with:

`XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: http://192.168.1.201/testdata.dat
Line Number 1, Column 5:`

The html code and the content of testdata.dat are below.

Although it says error, the page actually works as expected, but I kind of wasn't satisfied and played around a bit. I found that if I rename `testdata.dat` to `testdata.csv` and adjust the html file accordingly, the error goes away.

Is this expected? Can someone shine a light on this?

dygraphs_test.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Test</h3>
<div id="graphdiv2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g2 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
    "testdata.dat",
    {
      labels: [ "Date", "Temperature", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5" ],
    } // options
  );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

testdata.dat:

```
2018/01/12 17:59:04,22.18,22.34,28.44,20.31
2018/01/12 17:59:06,22.19,22.68,28.44,20.14
2018/01/12 17:59:08,22.18,22.32,28.44,20.31
2018/01/12 17:59:10,22.18,22.35,28.38,20.31
2018/01/12 17:59:12,22.18,22.37,28.38,20.31
2018/01/12 17:59:14,22.18,22.39,28.44,20.31
```

Comment: You have comma separated values (CSV), not an XML document, which puts data in a different syntax

Comment: Dygraphs does exactly the same in their front page example. On http://dygraphs.com/ they use "ny-vs-sf.txt" as the filename that holds the csv data. The syntax for http://dygraphs.com/data.html#url for the data source does not mention that the link is parsed according to the file ending, and nowhere does it say XML.

Comment: Looks like I can't re-vote to close, but this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630246/xml-parsing-error-in-firefox-developer-console